# How to differentiate between data posted by HTML generated by an ASP.Net Repeater Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

So I am using a Repeater inside a form to display a list of questions that are retrieved from a database.
Each Question allows the end user to select Yes or No and add some additional Text like this.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Panel runat="server">
   <asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="YesNo" ID="YesNo" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
      <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
   </asp:RadioButtonList>
  </asp:panel>
  <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="MoreInfo">
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="70px" Rows="10" Columns="25" Wrap="true" runat="server" CssClass="MoreInfoText"></asp:TextBox>
  </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The repeater is databound to a datatable in the PageLoad event.
One on the fields in the datatable is the Question's number. 
So when the data is posted how can I tell which question # each answer (Yes or No and additional Text) is refering to?

If I were generating the HTML by hand instead of using a Server Control I could just make the name of the html element that will be posting data like

```
name=variableHoldingQuestionNumber + YesNo
name=variableHoldingQuestionNumber + AdditionalComments
```

But I can't seem to use a variable when setting the Name attribute inside a Repeater Item.
Is abandoning the Server Control and writing the HTML myself my only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the questions number to a hidden field and when the save comes back, grab that hidden field back off and take the number out of it. Then you know which question you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on page load and do a postback. Take a deep look at Request.Form key/value pair collection. Everything from the post will be in there, with predictable labels/indexs.

Comment: I can see everything posting correctly but the issue is how can I associated each answer with a Question Number which is a field in the DataTable the repeater is bound to?

Comment: Bind it into a hidden value like @Fourth suggests, or base it off matching indexes. You know the order the data went into the repeater after all.  I only mentioned the Request.Form data as it's always there as a fallback when your in a situation that makes it difficult to find control references, such as dynamic rows in a repeater.